# How long will a version of a Python package be available on PyPI?

Tags: pypi

I would like to distribute an application that depends on several PyPI-packaged libraries. I have carefully selected certain versions of some of these libraries as newer versions (in some cases) are incompatible. My installer downloads them (with `pip`) at install-time and sets up the environment for the application. But how long are those versions going to be available? 6 hours? 2 years? Anything in between?

I'm basically looking for some sort of policy that tells me how long those versions of libraries are going to be hosted on PyPI (and who makes that decision).

**In-before-"distribute them yourself"**: That is an answer to a different question.
This is really about how PyPI works, not how I distribute my application.

Answer (score 1):

The friendly people in `#python` tell me that authors can delete any version of their packages at any time.

The only way to indemnify yourself against a version of something becoming nuked is to (assuming their license allows it) ship it yourself.

There is an argument for continuous integration against the latest versions on PyPI but that does assume there will be a new version and that the author doesn't just delete the whole thing. CI is just a good practice here, not a panacea.